# Installing asdf: Path doesn't seem to be recognized?

Tags: asdf, asdf-vm

I'm trying to install asdf on Debian 11.
After install, I still get this error:

```
bash: asdf: command not found
```

Suspect:  I'm sourcing something incorrectly.

Here's the script I'm using to install with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install prerequisites
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y curl git

export https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8082

    # Install asdf
    git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.11.3
    
    # Add asdf to the bash shell
    echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
    echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
    
    # Add asdf to the git shell
    echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.gitbashrc
    echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.gitbashrc
    
    # Activate asdf in the current shell
    source ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.gitbashrc
```

I've tried adding manually to .bashrc & .gitbashrc.  Here's what .bashrc & .gitbashrc look like:

.bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.asdf/bin"
. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"
```

.gitbashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.asdf/bin"
. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"
```

I've tried with and without the export path command.

I've reloaded the terminal, but every time I try to call asdf I get something like this:

```
user@user:~$ asdf plugin add erlang https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang.git
bash: asdf: command not found
```

/.asdf folder exists and has the files in it.
For some reason the shell just isn't finding it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend removing the path-prepending you do:

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.asdf/bin"
```

In the case of asdf, it doesn't do anything because no executables are located in `~/.asdf/bin`. When you `source ~/.asdf/asdf.sh`, it already prepends the necessary stuff to the path.

To debug this, I would recommend trying the following

- Run `set -x` in any scripts or interactively before sourcing `~/.asdf/asdf.sh` to ensure it is actually doing so
- Make sure that you are running `bash` and not `dash` (in the case of `dash`, the `~/.profile` file is read instead of `~/.bashrc`

Besides these tips, there isn't anything much I can do because it seems like some setup issue on your specific computer.